# How to Binding html to a WebView

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-8

i was searching about how to binding html in webview and i found this:

```
public static class WebBrowserHelper
{

public static readonly DependencyProperty HtmlProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "Html", typeof(string), typeof(WebBrowserHelper), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnHtmlChanged));

public static string GetHtml(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
{
    return (string)dependencyObject.GetValue(HtmlProperty);
}

public static void SetHtml(DependencyObject dependencyObject, string value)
{
    dependencyObject.SetValue(HtmlProperty, value);
}

private static void OnHtmlChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var browser = d as WebView;

    if(browser == null)
        return;

    var html = e.NewValue.ToString();

    browser.NavigateToString(html);
}
```

}

and the xamls code should be that

```
<WebView Grid.Column="1" Height="628" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" cxi:WebBrowserHelper.Html="{Binding Question.Body}" />
```

but i can't acces this property in xaml, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting? Does it compile?

Comment: it`s not even compiling, i can`t acces this property on webview tag. the only message that i have is that it can`t find this property

Comment: Try making WebBrowserHelper into "public abstract class WebBrowserHelper : DependencyObject" and see if that helps. Taken from example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701833.aspx. Maybe Windows Store API is finicky with attached properties.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're following the sample listed [here](http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/binding-html-to-the-web-browser-control).

Without seeing your full XAML listing, I'm going to guess that you don't have a namespace declaration for the **cxi** namespace. You probably copied the code from the page and pasted it into your own class that's in your own namespace. You need to make sure you have a namespace prefix defined for the namespace where this class resides before you can use it.

Lets say you defined **WebBrowserHelper** in the 'MyStuff' namespace. You would use:

```
xmlns:ms="using MyStuff"
```

At the top of your xaml file. Then later you would use

```
ms:WebBrowserHelper.Html
```

So you'd use the **ms** prefix instead of the **cxi** prefix.

Dev support, design support and more awesome goodness on the way: http://bit.ly/winappsupport